# R normalize dataframe column using max

Tags: r, max, aggregate, normalization, apply

R newbie.

I have seen some posts on creating functions to normalize data based upon the standard deviation, etc. But my problem is a bit different.

I have a large dataframe. I want to a. find the mean across all names in the dataset. b. normalize the mean values based upon the max value. Sample data:

```
df<- data.frame(name=c("lauren", "max", "lauren", "pat"), value=(1:4))
```

to get the mean I have:

```
meanValue <-aggregate(value ~name, data=df, mean)
```

output should be:

```
df<- data.frame(name=c("lauren", "max", "pat"), normalizedMean=c(.5, .5, 1))
```

but I'm stuck on how to get the max and create a new variable in the corresponding df dataframe. I know this is an apply function, but I have a suspicion that aggregate can be combined here.

Comment: You should make your example reproducible with `set.seed()` if you are going to use random values. Also, you should give the output you desire for your sample input.

Comment: Can't you just divide by the max() of your meanValue? meanValue$value/max(meanValue$value) might be what you want.

Comment: After your second line of code, do `meanValue$normalizedMean <- meanValue$value / max(meanValue$value)`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: The word "normalize" is in desperate need of a definiton. Most statisticians would think it meant "transform" or "scale" to a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. And how can you expect anyone to provide an answer when half of your data (the groups with a single element) has no standard deviation.

Comment: @RamNarasimhan thats exactly what I need. way simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
df<- data.frame(name=df$name, 
   normalizedMean=meanValue$value/max(meanValue$value))
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you posted as the final solution isn't the normalized value exactly. it should be c(0,0,1)

```
df<- data.frame(name=c("lauren", "max", "lauren", "pat"), value=(1:4))

meanValue <-aggregate(value ~name, data=df, mean)

min_val<-min(meanValue$value)
max_val<-max(meanValue$value)
meanValue$normalizedMean<-(meanValue$value-min_val)/(max_val-min_val) #normalizing

meanValue
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is using the same definition of normalization as you are ...

Comment: But what is his definition,Ben? It looks like statistical nonsense.

Comment: They just want to divide the means by the maximum mean.  There's not enough context here to know whether that's sensible or not.